# Why do YCbCr channels saved as jpeg images,the pixels' values change?

Tags: matlab, image-processing, rgb

I used the function [`rgb2ycbcr`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/rgb2ycbcr.html) in matlab R2013a to change RGB to YCBCR color space. And I saved each channel of YCBCR as a jpeg image.Then I read the jpeg image,for example CB channel,but I found the pixel value is different in the jpeg image with the channel CB before saved. Why does this happen? Here is my code:

```
I = imread('pic.jpg');  % // 'pic.jpg' is an unin8 rgb image
YCBCR = rgb2ycbcr(I);
Y = YCBCR(:,:,1);
CB = YCBCR(:,:,2);
CR = YCBCR(:,:,3);

imwrite(Y,'F:\CASIA V1.0\Y.jpg','jpg');
imwrite(CB,'F:\CASIA V1.0\CB.jpg','jpg');
imwrite(CR,'F:\CASIA V1.0\CR.jpg','jpg');
```

Then I read the `CB.jpg`, I found the pixel value is different with those in `YCBCR(:,:,2)`. Is anything wrong with my code? I will be very grateful if anybody can answer my question.

Answer (score 2):

When you use imwrite to store an image as a jpg, it runs jpeg compression on the image before saving it to file. By default, the compression quality is set to 75% of the original. I'm guessing this is the reason behind some pixel values changing from the uncompressed images to the compressed ones.